# Dynamic SQL Query: Replace all single quotes to double quote

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a dynamic SQL query and some params are being passed in such as this

```
Set @SQL = 'Update Table1 Set Status = 1 Where ' +
'Name = ''' + Cast(@Name As Varchar(50)) + '''' +
' Product = ''' + Cast(@Product As Varchar(50)) + ''''
```

I have issues with the single quote being passed in the param. If the @Name and @Product has no single quote at all, I won't have any issue. But sometimes the @Name or @Product would have single quote and that causes failure to execute my dynamic query as it's not properly formatted because of the additional single quote.

I have lots more param other than @Name and @Product, and I don't want to do something like `REPLACE(@Name, '''','''''')` for every single param unless it's necessary.

Is there a way that I can replace every single quote to double in my dynamic query before execution or better alternative?

Comment: There is no other alternative to it. I would suggest to create a function instead of writing REPLACE(@Name,'''','''''')

Answer (score 0):

Alternative but more hard work here:

```
Set @SQL = 'Update Table1 Set Status = 1 Where ' +
'Name = Cast(@Name As NVarchar(50)) ' +
' Product = Cast(@Product As NVarchar(50)) '

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL , N'@Name NVARCHAR(50), @Product NVARCHAR(50)', @Name, @Product
```

Let me know, if this worked for you ?